# PHP global array not showing

Tags: php, html, global-variables, global

Consider the following function which fills an array with strings(questions):

```
global $questions;
function printQuestions($lines){
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
        if($line_num%3 == 1){
            echo 'Question '.$count.':'.'<br/>'.'<input type="text" value="' . $line . '" class="tcs"/>'.'<br/>';
            $count++;
            $questions[] = $line;
        }
    }
}
```

The questions array is defined as global but it's not accessible outside the function. The following code block located at the bottom of the page returns nothing:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        foreach($questions as $qs)
            echo $qs;   
        }
?>
```

I know I could use session variables but I'm interested in this particular problem regarding global variables. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: using global is not a recommended practice, you could pass the values to the function just as you pass it $lines

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should move `global` inside the function.

```
function printQuestions($lines){
    global $questions;
    // ...
```

The [`global`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword brings a global variable into local scope, so you can operate on it. If you don't use `global` in the `printQuestions()` function to bring the global `$questions` variable in the scope of the function, then `$questions` will be local and will be a different variable than the global one you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use global variables in PHP as $GLOBALS["foo"] so in your case inside the function replace $questions with $GLOBALS["questions"] and everything should work.